# How do I define admin permissions in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am making a web app but I'm a little confused as to how I should give elevated permissions for the administrators. For instance, here, I want regular users to be read-only and admins to obviously have read and write permissions. How should I go about defining that? Any insight would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to your user accounts. It is also common to add a 'role' field (or similar) to user documents in Firestore.

That alone doesn't do you any good. You also need to protect your reads and writes with [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) where you can check if the user requesting a resource has a access to the document.

Comment: That answers all of my questions. Thank you very much, friend.